# When does the code outside React Component class in a JS file run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Say I have a JS file contains 2 React Component class definition and a bunch of other things:

```
// a file called OuterComponent.react.js

import xxx from xxx;
import yyy from yyy;

// When does these run?
let a = 0;
a = 1;

export default class OuterComponent extends React.PureComponent<> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       <InnerComponent />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class InnerComponent extends React.PureComponent<> {
  //... something
}
```

**Questions**

1. When will the declaration and value setting code for 'a' run? Does it run when this file is imported/required by other files?
2. Can I have some flag in this file and changes from time to time, and then read the value of this flag from many other files? (like a singleton manager?) If I can, how do I export it and import it?
3. What does creating multiple files actually mean? (except that it breaks huge chunk of code into small chunks for better readability) Does it make any other difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question 1: When will the declaration and value setting code for 'a' run? Does it run when this file is imported/required by other files?

Runs the *first* time the file is imported. It is not executed on subsequential imports.

> Question 2: Can I have some flag in this file and changes from time to time, and then read the value of this flag from many other files? (like a singleton manager?) If I can, how do I export it and import it?

You can.

Exporting:

```
export let a = 0;
```

Importing:

```
import { a } from './filename.js';
```

> Question 3: What does creating multiple files actually mean? (except that it breaks huge chunk of code into small chunks for better readability) Does it make any other difference?

- Breaks code into small chunks;
- Allows reuse; and
- Enables encapsulation of non-exported variables/functions.

--

Check a **demo of modules usage: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ImgQj2KzLj9O1D63Gq9?p=preview**

Notice how `a.js` is loaded only once, even though it is imported both by `b.js` and `c.js`. Also see how it is exported and imported, and how when it changes, the change is picked up in other modules.

Comment: For question 3, does that mean, for JS, each file is a 'namespace' or 'package' as in other languages?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Not really a namespace, because in some languages the namespace/package acts as a prefix. It's more like encapsulation, really. What is not exported is guaranteed to be inaccessible from outside. Similarly, if you want to use something inside a module, you must import it (or use global variables, which depends on the environment -- browser, node, etc.).

Comment: Ah, it can be seen as a namespace considering each module has its set of identifiers, meaning one identifier `a` declared in a module `a.js` does not collide with an identifier `a` declared in a module `b.js`. (Even if `a.js` exports its `a`, you can import it with a different name -- not `a` -- in `b.js`.)

Comment: I tried playing your demo code and noticed that you can't seem to change the value of 'stuff' from b.js even if it's imported there?

Comment: Also, for question 1, what if you are only importing certain part of the file, for example, in other file: ``` import {OuterComponent} from 'OuterComponent.react.js' ``` Would the extra content about ```a``` still run?

Comment: Yes, it runs, otherwise the module-loader wouldn't know that file actually exported that component.

Comment: About changing `a.stuff` from `b.js`, you really can't because imports create constant identifiers in the importer's scope. You should get an error if you try to change it (just don't know if this error is standardized in all browsers and node).

Answer (score 2):

okay here it is

Answer 1: Yes, it runs when you import this file.

Answer 2: You can define some varible and export it to use in some other file, but that we do for constant values that does not change over time, like your action types etc, the thing you are referring to here is not what it is for, you want to use react Context or Redux store for that.

Answer 3: Creating multiple files is a modular approach to code, React emphasis on Composition that is the whole point of composing components in one another and build an App

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. This code will run immediately when the file is imported. It has nothing to do with react but with how js works.
2. You can share a variable in js using `export` keyword like this:
   `export let a = 0`
   Changes to this variable won't rerender your components because it's not part of any state.
3. Readability is huge impact by itself. It also allows reuse of variables names.
   When working in collaboration it makes the flow much easier and reduces conflicts to only the places where they really are.